# How to add Square Bracket to every value of every columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a 25 columns . I want to add a [ ] (square Bracket of evry value of a columns present in the dataFrame.**

Comment: Output shuld be one element lists? Or strings?

Comment: please produce a sample code

Comment: Somewhere it's like : apple, banana, car    and in some column it's like ; apple.  Only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply to the entire dataframe you can use:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: f'[{x}]' if x else x)
```

For changing the column names you could try:

```
df.columns = [f'[{x}]' for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: I dont want to on Column .. I want on values of a column @vtasca

Comment: @abc See my edited answer.

Comment: yes i saw , but it apply where the value is empty also

Comment: @abc I have edited again, please see updated answer.